# Using match and apply in R

Tags: r, match, apply

```
> df = data.frame(id = 1:5, ch_1 = 11:15,ch_2= 10:14,selection = c(11,13,12,14,12))
> df
  id ch_1 ch_2 selection
1  1   11   10        11
2  2   12   11        13
3  3   13   12        12
4  4   14   13        14
5  5   15   14        12
```

Given this data set I need an additional column that follow the rules:

1. if selection is one of the two choices (ch_1 and ch_2), return the number of the choice (1 or 2)
2. if the selection is not of the two choices, return 3

I need a way to do this for every row. For a single row, doing the following code works just fine, but I can't seem to find a way to use it with `apply` to run it to each single row of a dataframe.Looking for a solution that can be applied to more than just two columns and that runs faster than doing a traditional loop

```
df=df[1,]

if (df$selection %in% df[,paste("ch_",1:2,sep="")]) {
  a = which(df[,paste("ch_",1:2,sep="")]==df$selection)
} else {
  a = 3
}
# OR
ifelse(df$selection %in% df[,paste("ch_",1:2,sep="")],1,3)
# OR
match(df$selection,df[,paste("ch_",1:2,sep="")])
```

Comment: Is there ever a case where there can be multiple columns that match?

Comment: @thelatemail No, all columns are necessarily different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the vector to the other columns with `==`, add a final column which is always `TRUE`, and then take the index of the first `TRUE` in each row using `max.col`

```
max.col(cbind(df$selection == df[c("ch_1","ch_2")], TRUE), "first")
#[1] 1 3 2 1 3
```

This should easily extend to *n* columns then.

Comment: I think this is way more idiomatic and elegant than `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when`, nice.

Comment: Accepting as the correct answer wasn't enough, just needed to leave a comment and say how elegant this is. Thank you @thelatemail

Comment: @r2evans - I thought I remembered seeing a `case_when` extension that could take a `list` as input somewhere, which could get around the need to write *n* statements. I haven't been able to dig it up again however.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this with nested `ifelse`,

```r
with(df, ifelse(selection == ch_1, 1L, ifelse(selection == ch_2, 2L, 3L)))
# [1] 1 3 2 1 3
```

but I'm rarely fond of nesting them. If this is all you need (and you never need more than two), then this might suffice.

One alternative is using `dplyr::case_when`,

```r
with(df, dplyr::case_when(selection == ch_1 ~ 1, selection == ch_2 ~ 2, TRUE ~ 3))
```

and it can be easily used within a `dplyr::mutate` if you are already using the package.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, but my original data has 15+ columns. Is there a way where I don't have to specify each instance of selection == ch_1, ch_2, ch_3... and so on?

Comment: Yes ... go with @thelatemail's answer :-)